# HTTP Status 404 error on jersy sample project

Tags: java, jax-rs, jax-ws, jersey-2.0

I am trying to run a sample restful web service application in eclipse.. But i am getting 404 error..

Java Code **UserService.java**

```
package com.test;

import javax.ws.rs.GET; 
import javax.ws.rs.Path; 
import javax.ws.rs.Produces; 
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/UserService")
public class UserService {
    @GET    
    @Path("/users")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getUsers() {
        return "Hai";
    }
}
```

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?> 
<web-app xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
   xmlns = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"  
   id = "WebApp_ID" version = "3.0"> 
   <display-name>TestWebService</display-name> 
   <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
   <servlet> 
      <servlet-name>TestWebService</servlet-name> 
      <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class> 
      <init-param> 
         <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name> 
         <param-value>com.test</param-value> 
      </init-param> 
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet> 
   <servlet-mapping> 
      <servlet-name>TestWebService</servlet-name> 
      <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern> 
   </servlet-mapping>   
</web-app>
```

when i invoke the application am getting the below error. But i am able to get the tomcat home page...

[image]

Comment: Had you tried only ../UserService/users (without the trailing slash)

Comment: 404 is page not found.  Have you looked into the logfiles if the application is deployed?

Comment: @freedev: tried that also.. it is not working

Comment: what happens when you go to /TestWebservice/ ?

Comment: @Jens i just run the project via tomcat server in eclipse.. not yet deployed the war..

Comment: /TestWebservice/  -- same error

Comment: Hi, are you sure, that the context root is "TestWebService"? I don't work with Eclipse, so I am not sure if it determines the context root according to the display-name, but Tomcat itselft doesn't. I do not use Tomcat often either, but to me it seems it uses the war file name (without extension) as context-root for your app. Would a pure servlet appear on the path you are expecting? Have you tried to simply build the war file, deploy it using tomcat manager app? (I did - created a project called "testApp" resulting in testApp.war and http://localhost:8080/testApp/rest/UserService/users worked.